# Json data as dict for cerberus validations

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to read Json file as string and using the data as validator for cerberus. I am using a custom function with check_with. The json works fine if I use the code from within my python test script.

abc.json

```
{ 
    "rows": {
        "type": "list",
        "schema": {
            "type": "dict",
            "schema": {
                "amt": {"type": "integer"},
                "amt": {"check_with": util_cls.amt_gt_than}
            }
       }
    }
}
```

python test code

```
with open("abc.json") as f:
    s = f.read()

#s = ast.literal_eval(s)
v = Validator()
r = v.validate(json_data, s)
```

Cerberus requires the variable s to be a dict and I can't convert abc.json file contents to json using json.load as the json is not a valid format. Any ideas on how to convert the string to dict?

Comment: what error are you getting? `json.load` convert a json string to a dict, so it should work for you

Comment: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value` error as the value for check_with key is not enclosed in double quotes

Comment: the json you have is not valid, `util_cls.amt_gt_than` should be included in double quotes